# Android memory usage - Do i need to nullify static variables?

Tags: java, android, memory-management, memory-leaks, static-members

Im currently undertaking a memory sweep of my application and i just have a quick question about what to do with `public static` variables within a class when the class is no longer required. An example of this is network requests:

```
public class NetworkRequest {

    public static String URL = "www.somestring.com/endpoint?withsomeparameters=true"

    public void perform(){
         // the rest of the request logic...
    }
}
```

After i have initiated this class like so:

```
NetworkRequest networkRequest = new NetworkRequest();

networkRequest.perform();
networkRequest = null;
```

Is my `public static` field preventing this class from being correctly garbage collected?

Then the same question again for:

- `public static final`
- `private static`
- `private static final`.

Thanks again for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, There is no problem with that static member. Garbage collector still can do its work for that object if there is no way to reach it.

> All objects in Java exist either on the heap or on the stack. Objects
>   are created on the heap with the new operator. A reference is then
>   attached to them. If the reference becomes null or falls out of scope
>   (e.g., end of block), the GC realizes that there is no way to reach
>   that object ever again and reclaims it. If your reference is in a
>   static variable, it never falls out of scope but you can still set it
>   to null or to another object.

Static variables serve as "roots" to the GC. As a result, unless you explicitly set them to null, they will live as long as the program lives, and so is everything reachable from them.

Answer (score 2):

No. Your class can be garbage collected when it is no longer used. That static field is the class using the String, not the String using your class.